# new WindowsIdentity() returns error "The encryption type requested is not supported by the KDC."

Tags: asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to get the groups from Active Directory that a user belongs to by creating a WindowsPrincipal object and then calling IsInRole() on it. However, as soon as try to create the WindowsPrincipal object like so:

```
WindowsIdentity winID = new WindowsIdentity("jdoe");
```

My program throws the following exception:

> "System.Security.SecurityException: The encryption type requested is
>   not supported by the KDC."

I'm at a loss. Where should I start to even find out what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site says the WindowsIdentity takes a 'User Principal Name': http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td3046fc.aspx

And this site defines what a User Principal Name is: http://searchexchange.techtarget.com/definition/User-Principal-Name

Also, note that the first site says:

> **This constructor is intended for use on computers joined only to Windows Server 2003 domains. An exception is thrown for other domain types.**

Here's  a codeplex project that shows how to query Active Directory: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28546/Active-Directory-Roles-Provider
If you are just trying to get the roles for the logged in user, and you are using Windows Authentication as your authentication method (spedified in web.config), all you have to do is use the User object that is available:
    WindowsIdentity winID = (WindowsIdentity) User.Identity;